# How would I pass an arg on the command line to a secondary program in pure c?

Tags: c

I have a small program that uses the command line. I want this program to be a driver program for other programs. I can get the driver program to read from the command line and execute the secondary program using the system function for now. So my question is once the secondary program has been executed, how do I pass an arg to it?

The secondary program is suppose to read a file and print the contents as output but its not. It does however work when I run the program separately and alone. When I try using the driver program on the secondary I get the usage error from the secondary program, which means the file needed in the secondary program, isn't getting the the file arg. Should the driver program be passing the file argument to the secondary program at runtime or should the secondary program be calling the file argument from the command line the moment its being executed?

The first program driver.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;

    int arg_count;
    int arg_index;

    for (arg_count = 0; arg_count < argc; arg_count++)
    {
        printf("argv[%2d]: %s\n", arg_count, argv[arg_count]);


        if (arg_count == 1)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[1], "-p") == 0)
            {
                system("C:/myProg/main.c");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The secondary program main.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE * process_in_file;
        int ch;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        usage(argv[0]);
    }

    if ((process_in_file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, " Unable to open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

        while( (ch=fgetc(process_in_file)) != EOF )
        {
           printf("%c", ch);
        }

    fclose(process_in_file);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The driver program must pass the argument when calling `system` and the secondary program can retrieve this argument via `argv`. The secondary program is already doing this, but the driver program is not passing any command-line arguments via `system`.

Comment: Just add the argument to the `system()` call: `system("C:/myProg/main.c filename");`

Comment: `if (arg_count == 1)` should probably not be inside the loop.

Comment: If the filename needs to be filled in dynamically, you can use `sprintf()` to create the argument to `system()`.

Comment: 1. You definitely will not execute the C program by calling `system` with its C source code file name.

Comment: sorry, I know that you cant use .c file in the system, lmao. For some reason, I thought it'd be easier to understand, then adding in all the details to make the secondary program a compiler program with the compiler exe in the file name. Just a quick run down of the problem. Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. `system("C:/myProg/main.c");` you cant execute `C` source files.

You need to form the full command including the parameters

```
char *formCommand(const char *progname, int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t length = strlen(progname) + 1;
    char *commandline;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        length += strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
    }
    commandline = malloc(length);
    if(commandline)
    {
        strcpy(commandline, progname);
        strcat(commandline, " ");
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            strcat(commandline, argv[i]);
            strcat(commandline, " ");
        }
    }
    return commandline;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system(formCommand("./myprog", argc, argv));
}
```